# How to create list of all unique combinations while keeping a total column for each combination?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique, combinations

I'm trying to find all possible unique combinations to make a sandwich. I also want to know how much each sandwich will cost. I have 3 sets of two lists, one list is for the item and the second is for the price of the item.

```
bread = ['italian', 'wheat', 'honey oat']
bprice = [1, 2, 3]
meat = ['roastbeef', 'ham', 'turkey', 'steak']
mprice = [3, 1, 2, 4]
vegetable = ['lettuce', 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'pickles']
vprice = [1, 4, 2, 3]
```

I'm trying to find all unique possible combinations, but I also want the total for each combination. The combination should contain one bread, one meat, and two different vegetables. For example:

Output:

```
          Combinations                Total
italian, ham, onions, pickles           9
italian, turkey, onions, pickles       ...
wheat, ham, onions, pickles            ...
```

I'm completely stuck on how to go about this. I researched itertools.product, but this seems to just get combinations and not the total. I also thought of indexing to get the price of the item, but again don't know how to combine that with the list of combinations, as well as dictionaries but am not sure how to incorporate that with getting a list of all combinations either. Are there any thoughts of how I can go about doing this?

Comment: First question, do you actually need a list of these? Or could just the total number suffice?

Secondly, Does order matter? This is important because normally in a combination order doesn't matter and I just want to make sure you don't want a permutation where order does matter.

Comment: What are you going to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd #To display the results
from itertools import combinations, product

# Create bread dictionary 
bread = ['italian', 'wheat', 'honey oat']
bprice = [1, 2, 3]
breaddict = dict(zip(bread, bprice))

# Create meat dictionary
meat = ['roastbeef', 'ham', 'turkey', 'steak']
mprice = [3, 1, 2, 4]
meatdict= dict(zip(meat,mprice))

# Create veggie dictionary
vegetable = ['lettuce', 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'pickles']
vprice = [1, 4, 2, 3]
vegdict=dict(zip(vegetable, vprice))

# The real work is done here
# Create combinations of two veggies
# Then use that combination with bread and meat to calculate a product of sandwiches
sandwiches = product(bread,meat,combinations(vegetable,2))

# Create empty dataframe for storage and display
df=pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate through sandwiches 
# and use unpacking tuple and map with dictionary to populate dataframe
for b, m, v in sandwiches:
    df=df.append(pd.concat([pd.Series(', '.join([b, m, *v])).rename('Combinations'),
                            pd.Series(sum([breaddict[b], 
                                           meatdict[m], 
                                           *map(vegdict.get, v)])).rename('Total')], 
                           axis=1))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                             Combinations  Total
0     italian, roastbeef, lettuce, onions      9
1   italian, roastbeef, lettuce, tomatoes      7
2    italian, roastbeef, lettuce, pickles      8
3    italian, roastbeef, onions, tomatoes     10
4     italian, roastbeef, onions, pickles     11
..                                    ...    ...
67    honey oat, steak, lettuce, tomatoes     10
68     honey oat, steak, lettuce, pickles     11
69     honey oat, steak, onions, tomatoes     13
70      honey oat, steak, onions, pickles     14
71    honey oat, steak, tomatoes, pickles     12

[72 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

#### Without pandas, but still using itertools.combinations and itertools.product

```
from itertools import combinations, product

bread = ['italian', 'wheat', 'honey oat']
bprice = [1, 2, 3]
breaddict = dict(zip(bread, bprice))

# Create meat dictionary
meat = ['roastbeef', 'ham', 'turkey', 'steak']
mprice = [3, 1, 2, 4]
meatdict= dict(zip(meat,mprice))

# Create veggie dictionary
vegetable = ['lettuce', 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'pickles']
vprice = [1, 4, 2, 3]
vegdict=dict(zip(vegetable, vprice))

# The real work is done here
# Create combinations of two veggies
# Then use that combination with bread and meat to calculate a product of sandwiches
sandwiches = product(bread,meat,combinations(vegetable,2))

sandwiches_with_price = [[b,m,*v], 
                          sum([breaddict[b], meatdict[m], *map(vegdict.get, v)])) for b, m, v in sandwiches]
sandwiches_with_price
```

Output:

```
[(['italian', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 9),
 (['italian', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 7),
 (['italian', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 8),
 (['italian', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 10),
 (['italian', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['italian', 'roastbeef', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 7),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 5),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 6),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 8),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'onions', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['italian', 'ham', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 7),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 8),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 6),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 7),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 9),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'onions', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['italian', 'turkey', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 8),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 10),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 8),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 11),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'onions', 'pickles'], 12),
 (['italian', 'steak', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 8),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 11),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'pickles'], 12),
 (['wheat', 'roastbeef', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 8),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 6),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 7),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 9),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'onions', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'ham', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 8),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 9),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 7),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 8),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'onions', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['wheat', 'turkey', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 11),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 9),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 12),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'onions', 'pickles'], 13),
 (['wheat', 'steak', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 9),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 12),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'onions', 'pickles'], 13),
 (['honey oat', 'roastbeef', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 9),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 7),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 8),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 10),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'onions', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'ham', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 10),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 8),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 9),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'onions', 'pickles'], 12),
 (['honey oat', 'turkey', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 10),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'onions'], 12),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'tomatoes'], 10),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'lettuce', 'pickles'], 11),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'onions', 'tomatoes'], 13),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'onions', 'pickles'], 14),
 (['honey oat', 'steak', 'tomatoes', 'pickles'], 12)]
```

Comment: Adding a plain python solution without pandas would help

Comment: @Pynchia  pandas is just there to align two list.   How, else do you display the "Output" in posted question? In my opinion the question is really answered with the "product and combinations" line.  Everything else is just dressing.

Comment: Thanks Scott for the help and the explanations, with using the without pandas version, is their a way I can sort it form least to greatest?

Comment: Try this:  `sorted(sandwiches_with_price, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose you have 2 vegetables, 1 meat and 1 type of bread per sandwich.

```py
bread = ['italian', 'wheat', 'honey oat']
bprice = [1, 2, 3]
meat = ['roastbeef', 'ham', 'turkey', 'steak']
mprice = [3, 1, 2, 4]
vegetable = ['lettuce', 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'pickles']
vprice = [1, 4, 2, 3]

# prices are easier to manage in a dict, let's do that.
prices = {x:y for x,y in zip(bread, bprice)}
prices.update({x:y for x,y in zip(meat, mprice)})
prices.update({x:y for x,y in zip(vegetable, vprice)})


#now let's make all the vegetable combinations:
combveg = [ sorted((x ,y)) for x in vegetable for y in vegetable if len(set([x,y])) == 2 ]

# remove duplicates
combveg = list(set([tuple(x) for x in combveg]))

# now calculate all the sandwich possibilities
sandwiches = [[b, m] + list(vgs) for b in bread for m in meat for vgs in combveg]

# just have to build their prices now
sandwiches_with_price = [(sandwich, sum([prices[item] for item in sandwich])) for sandwich in sandwiches]
```

most of the list manipulations could be chained, or optimized using some generator expressions, but the goal was to explain each step.

Answer (score 1):

Another pure Python solution.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import product, combinations

bread = ['italian', 'wheat', 'honey oat']
bprice = [1, 2, 3]
meat = ['roastbeef', 'ham', 'turkey', 'steak']
mprice = [3, 1, 2, 4]
vegetable = ['lettuce', 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'pickles']
vprice = [1, 4, 2, 3]

d = dict()
d.update(zip(bread, bprice))
d.update(zip(meat, mprice))
d.update(zip(vegetable, vprice))

for p in product(bread, meat, combinations(vegetable, 2)):
    # make 1 tuple from list and tuple (from combinations)
    p = p[0:2] + p[2]
    print('{:<40} = {}'.format(', '.join(p), sum(itemgetter(*p)(d))))
```

It uses the *product* of the items (used by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387468/how-to-create-list-of-all-unique-combinations-while-keeping-a-total-column-for-e/63387784#63387784))

Also, it has a dictionary *slice*:

```
itemgetter(*p)(d))
```

This fetches the prices for the (bread, meat, vegetables product ***p*** from the dictionary ***d***)

The following line of code:

```
p = p[0:2] + p[2]
```

This was hacky but I didn't know another way to get the tuple produced by `combinations(vegetable, 2)` to single items instead of the tuple it produces.

Prints:

```
italian, roastbeef, lettuce, onions      = 9
italian, roastbeef, lettuce, tomatoes    = 7
italian, roastbeef, lettuce, pickles     = 8
italian, roastbeef, onions, tomatoes     = 10
italian, roastbeef, onions, pickles      = 11
italian, roastbeef, tomatoes, pickles    = 9
italian, ham, lettuce, onions            = 7
. . .
honey oat, steak, lettuce, tomatoes      = 10
honey oat, steak, lettuce, pickles       = 11
honey oat, steak, onions, tomatoes       = 13
honey oat, steak, onions, pickles        = 14
honey oat, steak, tomatoes, pickles      = 12
```